# bar and line chart together, getting error ordinal must be >=1

Tags: matplotlib, charts

```py
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(sharex=True, figsize=(20,20))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
coeff_df[['USRealRate_cont','USHY_spread_cont','VIX_cont', 'DXY_cont']].plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax1)
coeff_df['EM_spread'].plot(color='green', linewidth='3', ax=ax2, secondary_y=True)
```

I tried to explicitly set the index of the dataframe to datetime, but this didn't help. Problem comes from the last row - it draws the bar chart actually. I looked at other similar error messages here as well, but couldn't find a solution.

Index dtype is `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`, dataframe itself contains floats.

Comment: `linewidth='3'` or `linewidth=3`?

Comment: Thanks. I think both should work, but this didn't solve it.